# pandas How to find all rows within 10 days of any date in a list of dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a list of dates, but I can't just use `df['date'].isin(list_of_dates)` because I also want any rows whose date is within 10 days of a date in my list. For example, if my dataframe had 5 rows whose dates were

```
  date    
02-04-21
30-03-21
22-03-21
18-03-21
12-03-21
```

and `list_of_dates = ["30-03-21", "05-03-21"]`

then I would want three first three rows because they are within 10 days of `"30-03-21"`, and also the last row because it is within 10 days of `"05-03-21"`. But not the fourth row.

Comment: it is possible that your list of dates may have more than two entries, right? Also how do you define 10 days? before? after?a bit more clarity, if you can

Comment: @sammywemmy Yes the list could have many entries, and I meant 10 days both before and after, so a 20 day period in total. If multiple periods overlap then the rows in the overlap should only be counted once, though we could deal with that after the fact by removing rows with the same index maybe. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [pandas.date_range()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) to generate all the possible dates.

```py
list_of_dates = ["30-03-21", "05-03-21"]

set_of_dates_expand = set()

for date in list_of_dates:
    set_of_dates_expand.update(pd.date_range(start=date, periods=10))
    set_of_dates_expand.update(pd.date_range(end=date, periods=10))

df['date'].isin(set_of_dates_expand)
```

Answer (score 0):

Target is change list ["30-03-21", "05-03-21"] to below list

```
Output

2021-03-30  0   
2021-03-31  0
2021-04-01  0
2021-04-02  0
2021-04-03  0
2021-04-04  0
2021-04-05  0
2021-04-06  0
2021-04-07  0
2021-04-08  0
```

use reample() function

```
list_of_dates = ["30-03-21", "05-03-21"]
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':list_of_dates})
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
s1=df['Date'].append(
pd.Series(df.loc[0,'Date']+pd.Timedelta('9D'))).append(
pd.Series(df.loc[1,'Date']+pd.Timedelta('9D')))
df1=df1.reset_index().set_index(0)
df1=df1.sort_index()
target=df1.iloc[:2,:].resample('D').fillna(method='ffill').append(
df1.iloc[2:,:].resample('D').fillna(method='ffill'))
```

Good luck~